# Bootstrap how to get help-block to work with inline and horizontal forms

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to setup a form using the Bootstrap form-horizontal layout with the controls in an inline layout while still being able to have the help-block text below each field.

I have been able to accomplish the desired layout using the code below.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <span class="control-label">Name</span>
                <div class="controls form-inline">
                    <input type="text" class="input-large" placeholder="First" id="FirstName">
                    <input type="text" class="input-mini" placeholder="M.I." id="FirstName">
                    <input type="text" class="input-large" placeholder="Last" id="LastName">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

However I would like to be able to add the help-block class to each field as shown below:

```
<input type="text" id="FirstName" class="input-large" >
<p class="help-block">First Name</p>
```

Example of what I am looking for:

[Example Image](http://dentconsent.com/example1.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: My preferred way of handling it is this answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28989568/399124

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do with Bootstrap, but you can do it with an extra markup and a little of CSS.

Demo: http://bootply.com/64777

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="my-special-form">
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="input-large" placeholder="First" id="FirstName">
                <p class="help-block">First Name</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="input-mini" placeholder="M.I." id="FirstName">
                <p class="help-block">M.I</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="input-large" placeholder="Last" id="LastName">
                <p class="help-block">Last</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.my-special-form div {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `boostrap3` it's supported to use `.row` and `.col`-classes to control forms appearance.

This gives you better control on various screen sizes than a horizontal form does. Please  have a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes

With the provided example from Boostrap3 you might solve it like this inside your form (without `.form-inline`).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-2">
    <p class="help-block">First Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-3">
    <p class="help-block">M.I</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-4">
    <p class="help-block">Last</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/housecarl/5H6qf/1/).

CSS (overriding some classes from bootstrap)

```
.help-block{line-height:0px;}
.controls{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
```

unfortunately, in small screen the control div blocks wide lenght of input