# Bootstrap form : Is there a way to have the .help-block larger than the input field?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a (long) form using Twitter Bootstrap3, and I have a design problem with small fields that need a long explanation.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>The form</legend>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="username">Username</label>  
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
        <span class="help-block">A very long explanation, that is longer than the above input field. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

If I replace the `col-md-5` class by `col-md-8`, it increases both input field and .help-block width (which is logic since they are both contained in the same div), this gives a too large input field in the layout.

Is there a way, using Twitter Bootstrap, to have a larger .help-block than the related input field, without loosing the "responsiveness" of the form ?

Comment: The long size defeats the whole purpose of `help-block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a different column for the `help-block` and offsetting the help-block containing div!

[Bootply example here](http://www.bootply.com/mrtXRtnRxH)

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="username">Username</label>  
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
      <span class="help-block">A very long explanation, that is longer than the above input field. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>  
      </div>
    </div>
```